# one unwrapped item for multiple textures/items

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

[image]

I unwrapped all the needed parts of my couch, but I can take a shortcut if the three pillows have the same texture coordinates as the first one I unwrapped, as you can see in the UV image editor (its outlined blue).

I want the same for the feet of the couch outlined green. How do I do connect the other items with the one that is already unwrapped?

I will probably texture in Photoshop, not in Blender, not sure if this relevant.

Comment: Easiest (and most resource optimal way) is to use instances. Just unwrap one pillow/foot/whatever, separate it from the main couch object and clone it in object mode. If you want it in one single object just copy the unwrapped pillow over the others with snapping, and delete the ones without texture coordinates.

Comment: Ok sounds fast. So after the one pillow i unwrapped, i can just copy that one in the 3D window and replace the other two? I copied them the same way before i unwrapped it. So doing it just after unwrapping should do the trick?

Comment: Yep, that's right. Either copy it directly in edit mode if you want a single object, or separate it into a new object and clone it, if you don't mind separate clone objects